# Laravel Blade echoing properties of child...properties?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**SETUP**

Model

```
    public function totalValidated()
     {
       return $this->hasOne('user')->where('validated', '=', "1")
       ->selectRaw('district_id, count(*) as total')->groupBy('district_id');
     }
```

Controller

```
$districts = District::select(array('id', 'name'))
            ->with(array('usersCount','totalValidated'))
            ->get();

return View::make('districts.index', compact('districts'));
```

I have the following data returned:

```
0: {
 id: 1,
 name: "Northern California",
  total_validated: {
    district_id: "1",
    total: 3
   }
 },
1: {
 id: 2,
 name: "Southern California",
  total_validated: {
    district_id: "2",
    total: 30
   }
 }
```

View

```
@foreach ($districts as $district)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$district->name}}</td><td>{{$district->total_validated->total}}<td>
  <tr>
@endforeach
```

**Question**

How do i display the "total" in "total_validated" per district?  The above only gets me a

```
 "Trying to get property of non-object"
```

which i know is wrong, but i'm not sure how to get the value out of that nested array.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the compact function messes up your object, but I haven't used Laravel in a while so I don't know what it does.

Comment: Please post your database structure. And try `$district->total_validated->pivot->total`

Comment: i'm accessing an array within an object. "Pivot" returns the same error.

Comment: Looks like you figured out yourself. ~~Then it should be like this: `$district->total_validated['total']` or `$district['total_validated']['total']`.~~

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's up with blade, but plain php worked

```
<?php echo($district['totalValidated']['total']) ?>
```